# if and for statement for the National inpatient sample

Tags: r

I have a dataset, attached. It has 16 columns.
The first column shows whether patients got surgery or not, and the other 15 are Day1-15 of surgery (coded as 1, 0).
I want to create a new column that satisfies a few conditions. I want that column to show the exact day of the procedure.
If column `Day3` for example has a value of 1, I want the new value in the new column to be 3 (if and only if the first column `crani` and `PRDAY3` column have a value of 1), and so on to be applied on all of the days' columns (day1-15).

Would really appreciate your help. Please let me know if you have any questions regarding the dataset or the problem I'm trying to solve.

```
tts <- function(timedc){
 for (i in 15) {
   if (TBI$PRDAYi == "1"){
     timedc = c(timedc, TBI$PRDAYi)
   } 
   return(timedc)  
 }
 
 for (i in TBI$crani){
   if (TBI$crani == "1"){
     tts
   }
 }
}
```

*When tts is time to surgery.

I'm getting this error message:

> Warning in if (TBI$crani == "1") { :
> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I want to create a column that has the exact day of the procedure from this database, as above.
dataset below.

```
> dput(TBI[1:10, 1:6])
structure(list(TBI.crani = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.PRDAY1 = c(NA, 
0, NA, NA, 1, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1), TBI.PRDAY2 = c(NA, 2, NA, NA, 
11, NA, NA, 0, 16, 2), TBI.PRDAY3 = c(NA, 2, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 
0, 0, 2), TBI.PRDAY4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, NA, NA, NA, 0, 5), 
    TBI.PRDAY5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 11, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Rlg.png)

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(TBI)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(TBI))`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edtited the queston @RuiBarradas please let me know what you think

Comment: It's better but 1) you have two data sets, `timedc` and `TBI`, which one have you posted? 2) `for(i in 15)` will only take one value, it should be `for(i in 1:15)`; 3) try `TBI$PRDAY[i]`, not `TBI$PRDAYi`; 4) the 2nd loop is on `TBI$crani`, so the `if` should be `if (i == "1")`; 5) after the `if` you have `tts` but that is the name of the function, not of a vector, you are calling the function recursively?

Comment: In my first comment above, I say to please edit **the question**. Please don't post data in comments. And it's missing something, as posted it's incomplete. And there are no `crani` or `PRDAY` columns.

Comment: @ruiBarradas, I only have one dataset (TBI) I created the timedc in hope to get a separate column that has continuous data of the exact date Of surgery (crani). 
If the cell==1 on PRDAY3 the value in the new column should be 3 and so on. My code is inherently wrong I believe. There are few mistakes. Not sure how to fix. Tts is the function I created in hope I can apply it to the for and if statement of Tbi$crani. Just lost here, sorry

Comment: Ok, but we still don't have data with the day columns, please post the output of `dput(TBI[1:10, 1:6])` in the question.

Comment: @RuiBarradas please find the data set added in the question (Edited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following function does what the question asks for. With the posted data it returns a vector of zeros, since the first column `TBI.crani` is always zero.

```
tts <- function(data){
  f <- function(x){
      if(all(is.na(x))) 
        NA_integer_ 
      else {
        w <- which(x == 1)
        if(length(w)) w[1] else 0L
      }
  }  
  crani <- grep("crani", names(data))
  day_cols <- grep("DAY", names(data))
  apply(data, 1, function(x){
    if(x[crani] == 1) f(x[day_cols]) else 0L
  })
}

tts(TBI)
TBI$NEW <- tts(TBI)
```

Comment: I feel this code will work, thank you. TBI.crani is not all zeros, it has few 1s in it. When I run the code, I get a simple error msg below
Error in x[["TBI.crani"]] : subscript out of bounds
what do you think about this?

Comment: @CodeRCodeP I believe the bug is corrected now. Can you run the code again?

Comment: the bug is corrected. Learned alot on how to use functions correctly. Thank you. However, I can retrieve the column where the function is applied. will the new column have the exact day the surgery was done. i.e the PRDAY column when it =1 and when crani==1?

Comment: @CodeRCodePYes, it will. As long as `crani == 1`, if it's `PRDAY1` the new column will be 1, if it's `PRDAY2` it will be 2, etc.

Comment: great. thank you. how can I retrieve the values of the new column created by the function?

Comment: @CodeRCodeP See at the end, the last code line. Change the new column name `NEW` at will.

Comment: You are a life saver, my friend.. I can't thank you enough @RuiBarradas